# MUI Datagrid disable user from typing further if validation does not pass

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mui-datatable

Is there any way to prevent a user from typing into a cell during edit mode if a validation fails? MUI documentation only shows validation in form of a snack bar but still allows users to continue to type.

In the below example, the field "data" should only allow the user to type up to 10 characters in length. The expected behavior would be to not record any new characters after 10.

**DataGrid Component So Far**

```
import React from "react";
import { DataGrid } from "@mui/x-data-grid";

export default function FairValuePricingLatest({ rows, handleCellEdit }) {
    const columns = [
    {
      field: "id",
      headerName: "Id"
    },
    {
      field: "data",
      headerName: "Data",
      editable: true,
      preProcessEditCellProps(params) {
        const invalid = params.props.value.length > 10;
        if (invalid) {
          return { ...params.props, error: invalid }
        }
      }
    ];

    return (
      <DataGrid
        editMode="cell"
        experimentalFeatures={{ newEditingApi: true }}
        processRowUpdate={handleCellEdit}
        rows={rows}
        columns={columns}
      />
    )
}
```